# Replace an element without JavaScript

Tags: html, css

For the sake of brevity, please consult this depiction of [my template](http://bit.ly/1yqtdWt) (*your web browser might give you a false positive about that website*), that [fiddle](http://bit.ly/1zDM2E1) made with a chunk of my code and a sample of my H.T.M.L. file.

```
<html>
    <!--[…]-->

    <body>
        <!--[…]-->

        <article>
            <div class="latest_article_preview">
                <img class="latest_article_thumbnail" src="16x9_ratioed_picture.jpg" width="222" height="124"></img>

                <div class="latest_article_headline">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                </div>

                <div class="latest_article_lede">
                    Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehi
                </div>

                <div class="read_more">
                    Read more…
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>

        <!--[…]-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Each latest_article_preview visually has three sub-divisions : latest_article_thumbnail, latest_article_headline and latest_article_lede. Technically, there is a fourth one (for now called "read_more") that shall visually replace latest_article_lede.
Wherever latest_article_preview gets hovered by the cursor, latest_article_lede shall be replaced by read_more.
Still, read_more is not a link to the article page as the entire latest_article_preview box is clickable (even before the to-be-animated transitions are over).

This has to be written in vanilla C.S.S., for I know two ways to do such an interaction :

1. The z-index transformation trick.
2. The content replacement.

I first tried the content replacement. As it terribly failed when I came to combine it with animations, I went to try the z-index transformation trick.

The reason I first avoided that trick is that I find it dirty. I still chose it anyhow. But I am bugging on something : how can I make the read_more flexible box take the exact same space as the latest_article_lede one ? I tried the C.S.S.'s Position property but the results were unsatisfying either (also, I remember absolute positioning being incompatible with animations).
I searched Google to know if I could base its size, positioning and alignment parameters on latest_article_lede's without finding any satisfying answer at all (despite being sure that the Flex property could help).

… After what I plan to add animations (mostly if not only fading effects), already having those. Animations that, as said earlier do not really go with the Content property.

Any samaritan to save me on this ? Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't replace content with CSS.

Comment: @ZachSaucier As I said, this is mostly a visual replacement. To me, a website's design has to use C.S.S. as long as JavaScript can be avoided for. I would rather use JavaScript for heavy client-side stuff such as games, text or graphics editors, calculators et cætera…

Comment: FYI, it's best to use the abbreviations CSS, HTML, etc. instead of H.T.M.L.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Far away from me any desire to get irritating but…  How is this relevant to the main topic ? (In fact, abbreviations, acronyms and initialisms are three different things and their syntaxes tend to vary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be a combination of `pointer-events` and `opacity`:

```css
section {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
section div {
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;

}
section div:after {
  content: 'Read more...';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all .2s;
  transform: translateZ(200px);
}
section div:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Headline</h1>
  <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit Amet!</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hum… Interesting. I already did experiments with :hover and :after pseudo-classes with no real success but I never even heard about this pointer-events property. I must admit I am surprised by how clean and far superior your solution is next to everything I tried. I will go to bed wiser tonight. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you like it. That specific piece of CSS makes a lot of assumptions and has magic numbers (namely, the 400px height). But this can be made to work without a specific height given either (depends on your browser support needs).

Comment: I adapted what you gave me with flexible boxes but, combined with animations et cætera, it fails to deliver the effect I want correctly. I still learnt a C.S.S. property so it helped in another way. I think I will just go with jQuery for a moment until I figure a cleaner way to do this (but I can say that, after a lot of research, I will have to wait C.S.S.'s next version). It bugs me a bit since I do not want to use JavaScript but it is just two or three lines…

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is. If you'd like, we can discuss this in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign).

Comment: A lot of changes to both my C.S.S. file's and your JSFiddle's structures, a bit of time and some research eventually allowed me to get what I wanted up and running. Thank you.

Comment: @RevoltXS Glad to hear!